# ionic page not draggable and not zoomable

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I have an ionic app with a long and wide table. I can scroll the table up and down. However, I cannot move the table left and right. This is a problem as the table has many columns. A nice feature would be that the page can be zoomable by using the 2-finger action.

Here is the relevant html code;

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl" class="container">
  <ion-content class="has-header" overflow-scroll="true">
    <ion-scroll zooming="true" direction="xy">
      <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-bordered">
      <!-- table contents -->
      </table>
    </ion-scroll>
  </ion-content>
</div>
```

How to use the ionic directives correctly to make the page draggable left and right as well as zoomable?

My target platform is Android 5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish what you wanted with the following:

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-scroll zooming="true" direction="xy" style="height:500px">
      <table ng-table="tableParams" style="width:600px">
        <!-- table contents -->
      </table>
    </ion-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

To me, the trick seemed to be not specifying the table width in percentage.

Comment: Maybe my table has too many columns. I cannot see the entire table on the screen.

Comment: @user1824987, you can see it when you pinch zoom out on the device.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Let me try it out. Upvoted and selected as answer.

Comment: Thank you. I tested on my lollipop android and it worked as expected, lemme know if it works for you too.

Comment: It did work. I can zoom and scroll left and right now. However, I can no longer scroll up and down. *Pulling out my hair!!* Wait. I think I made a mistake. Check again.

Comment: Thanks. I checked again and I confirm this is indeed a problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97181/discussion-between-prashant-ghimire-and-user1824987).

Comment: Latest answer confirmed to be working. All problems solved. I wish I can give you 10 votes.

Comment: @Prashant Ghimire i used your example but my picture is not zoomable....it can be pushed arround but i can't zoom out or zoom in can you help

Comment: @lewis4u could you please post that as a seperate question and also add the codes that you have? Thanks.

Comment: Which one exactly? sorry i am focused on something

Comment: I have solved this...now i can zoom in and out and drag the content inside ionic app. I see no reason to post the question...maybe i should post an answer?